# 'mysql_upgrade' Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' on M1 Mac

Tags: installation, mariadb, homebrew, apple-m1

I followed the macos installation of MariDB on their website and I always get this error when I try to run `mysql_upgrade`

I also can't secure the installation due to the same error

```
Reading datadir from the MariaDB server failed. Got the following error when executing the 'mysql' command line client
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I tried following tutorials but they don't work.

What should I do?

### **EDIT**

Sorry, I forgot I posted a question here.

It's all good now! I was able to make it work. All I did was use `mariadb -u root -p` instead, and the password was `root`.

The tutorial I used was the one from Mariadb's official website.

As for this solution, I forgot where I got it from but, kudos to you who helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted which tutorials you have followed.
Have you tried

```
mysql_upgrade -p
```

it will prompt for root password. You can even run it with a different user using the `-u` option.

Hope this helps.

FYI: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_upgrade/

Comment: If you are still facing the issue after performing _mysql_upgrade_, then try stopping the MySQL service and then start it again (Do not perform restart).

Answer (score 0):

I had this error running a docker container of yobasystems alpine mariadb with nextcloud. I upgraded my database image to a new version, but this command was required to actually perform the update in docker, which was not straight forward to figure out. What worked for me was:

```
docker exec -it nextcloud-db /bin/sh -c 'mysql_upgrade -u root -p nextcloud -h db'
```

Then typing in my mysql root password when promted.

nextcloud-db is my container name
nextcloud is database name
db is my host name, not localhost which this command defaults too without the -h [host]

Hope this helps someone else who got stuck where I did. I am going to set up a script to run this for me when the container version is upgraded.